# Redirect URL from gwt project with post parameters data

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I would like to redirect the URL from gwt project to other simple servlet project with post parameter.
How can I redirect with post parameters data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [FormElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/FormElement.html), add the parameters and then submit it.